# Combining keycode events in jQuery

Tags: jquery, keyboard, keyboard-events, keycode

I'm building a virtual keyboard in jQuery, using keycode events to tigger an append, but keycode combinations are throwing me for a loop. Here's an example:

I want to append a questionmark only when both the SHIFT key (keycode 16) and slash key (keycode 191) are pressed together. I thought the && operator would help, but this only appends the slash:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) { 

    if (e.keyCode == 16 && e.keyCode == 188  ) { 
         $('#mydiv').append('<span>?</span>');
     }

});
```

Any suggestions or idea why && isn't working, and what might work? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Checking `e.keyCode == 16 && e.keyCode == 188` won't do anything useful because `e.keyCode` won't be both 16 and 188 at the same time. The `&&` operator is a logical conjunction so it evaluates to true if the expressions on both sides of it are true.

I think you want to look at `e.shiftKey`; if that's true then the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is down, if `e.shiftKey` is false then <kbd>Shift</kbd> is not down:

```
if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 191) {
    // ?
}
else if(!e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 191) {
    // /
}
```

Comment: using e.shiftKey has the problem of appending both the non shiftkey character and shiftkey character. example: e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 188 returns / and ?.

Comment: for every e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 191, there's also a simple e.keyCode == 191. so the shiftkey event appends both the shifted character (?) and the unshifted character (/).

Comment: @pardon: I don't follow you. That jsfiddle.net only shows question marks for me, no slashes.

Comment: that's because it only has half the functionality i'm looking for. here's what was giving me both characters: http://jsfiddle.net/pardon/GUwmz/1/ and here's how i solved it: http://jsfiddle.net/pardon/8HHKN/

Comment: @pardon: Sorry, I though checking `!e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 191` (or some equivalent) was clear.

Comment: This approach would fail when the user release the shift key quickly(the user is still able to enter something like #,$) instead keep holding the shift keep and then press the other.

Answer (score 0):

Because each key creates its own keydown event, it will never be possible for `keyCode` to equal both 16 and 188.

Luckily the SHIFT state is stored in `event.shiftKey` :)

Comment: shiftkey appends both the "shifted" character and the non-shifted character :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.shiftKey){
     if (e.which == 188) { 
         alert('both');
     }

  }
});
```

Comment: that got close. i just solved it!

    $(document).keydown(function(e) { 
        if (e.keyCode == 191) { 
            if (e.keyCode == 191 && e.shiftKey){
                $('#myDiv').append('<span>?</span>');
            }
            else {
                $('#myDiv').append('<span>/</span>'); 
            }
        }
    });