# Browser independent keycode handling with jQuery

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, jquery-events

Does jQuery support translation of browser dependent keycodes for independent programming? I got some code like this

```
$("#container").delegate("input", "keyup", function(event){
    if(event.which == 107){
        event.preventDefault();
        addSomething();         
    }
});
```

which is supposed to append some new elements to my `$(document)` when `+` is pressed. Obviously this is not working in Chrome for instance, because Chromes' keycode for `+` happend to be 187. I thought, this should be a frequent problem and presumed, there is a way to use a different information from the `event` which is already browser independent?  I found out, there is a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962025/combining-keycode-events-in-jquery) for `shift`-key. But does this apply to all keys and is this proved to work in every browser? I think of something like

```
...
if(event.+){ //or maybe if(event.plus){
...
```

Comment: `event.which` for the `+` key is 43 in all my browsers (Chrome, Opera, Firefox and Safari), which matches the ASCII code for the `+` character.

Comment: I am using a german keyboard which looks like [this](http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3142/3039005424_5211cd51cb.jpg). Could be that I am facing a bigger problem..

Comment: Check if you're getting different values in `event.charCode` and `event.keyCode`. Apparently, 187 would be the "right-pointing double angle quotation mark" (`»`), which does not seem right even for your keyboard layout.

Comment: oh, you are right! My `keypress` event is 43 either, but my `keyup` event is 187 in Chrome!

Answer (score 0):

There is https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/blob/master/jquery.hotkeys.js , by Tzury Bar Yochay and John Resig.  That handles just about any key[down/up/press] situation.